Заполнение id по порядку без явной передачи в базу
Можно ли в таблице при вставке id, к примеру, сделать так, чтобы id выставлялись по порядку без явного указания. В Postgres умею, в ClickHouse не выходит, не могу найти в документации

https://yandex.ru/search/?text=ClickHouse+autoincrement+site%3Astackoverflow.com

спасибо большое)
